# Scaling nginx-rtmp livestreaming with ffmpeg transcoding

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp, http-live-streaming

I currently have a functional livestreaming setup using the prolific `nginx-rtmp` library, and I'm using `ffmpeg` to provide various resolutions of my stream.

The only problem is, `ffmpeg` with only 2 outputs eats up ~50% of my CPU. I'd like to be able to support up to 20 streamers at once – with the current demand, that would mean I need 10x the CPU power that I currently have!

**How can I scale my transcoding setup with `nginx-rtmp` and `ffmpeg`?**

```
rtmp {
server {
    listen 1935;

    application src {
        live on;
        exec_push ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/src/$name
            -c:v copy -preset:v ultrafast -b:v 512K -c:a copy -tune zerolatency -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/$name_hi
            -c:v libx264 -preset:v ultrafast -s 852x480 -b:v 128K -c:a copy -tune zerolatency -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/$name_low;

            # -c:v libx264 -s 852x480 -b:v 128K -c:a copy -tune zerolatency -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/$name_low;
            # -c:v libx264 -s 1280x720 -b:v 256k -c:a copy -tune zerolatency -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/$name_mid;
    }

    application hls {
        live on;
        hls on;
        hls_path /tmp/hls;

        # hls_fragment 1s;
        # hls_playlist_length 4s;
        hls_fragment 4s;
        hls_playlist_length 12s;
        hls_nested on;
        hls_variant _low BANDWIDTH=160000;
        # hls_variant _mid BANDWIDTH=320000;
        hls_variant _hi  BANDWIDTH=640000;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: how you finally proceeded with the problem? Means what solution you finally deployed.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t without sacrificeing quality. If there was a way, ffmpeg would enable it by default. Your best option is to add a hardware encoder or two, like an Nvidia card with nvenc (make sure you get the expensive one with unlimited streams, most are limited to two).

Comment: Thanks for the response – how about a cloud based solution? I'm thinking ECS + Fargate could scale up my transcoding based on demand... I'm not sure what this looks like in practice though.

Comment: If your going that route, just use a service like mux.com, or Zencoder.

Comment: I'm concerned that using services would get too expensive for me... Although with auto scaling on AWS, costs could easily get out of control as well.

Comment: I would be more concerned with developing, and maintaining a video system in a very fluid market with very complicated workflows.

Comment: That's a good point. I guess another benefit of not using a service is being able to integrate my video service with my app.

For example, when a VOD is created after a livestream, being able to store that VOD's url in my app DB.

Answer (score 0):

Our time tested, production system that is cost effective -

Use a Linode (or any other cloud VPS) - in our case, a full HD stream with 60fps multicast to YouTube/FB costs around 2-3 USD for 4hours... for a 16GB RAM dedicated server with 320GB SSD.

From OBS/Hardware encoder, send to this RTMP Server...

Using Linode StackScript, we can automate the configuration and provisioning of the RTMP server...

So this is kinda use and throw server that is cheap...